# Nagios - How to Set Alert Frequency?

Tags: alert, monitoring, nagios

This should be pretty simple, but I can't seem to find the right setting. We are getting email spam too often from Nagios and want to adjust it to notify less often. How can I change this setting?

We are using Nagios Core (latest version).

Answer (score 1):

yep, this is pretty easy to achieve.
According to on-line [manual](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/objectdefinitions.html#service), you should use `notification_interval` directive.

The `notification_interval` is by default in minutes (determined by the value of [`interval_length`](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/configmain.html#interval_length)), so if you set to `1440` then Nagios will **re-notify** you only once per 24 hours for a specific service/host.